# Как указать подключаемому (include) файлу кодировку?

Tags: php

Как указать подключаемому (include) файлу кодировку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак, кодировка указывается при сохранении.

Можно переконвертировать вывод

```
ob_start();
include 'file.php';
$result = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $result);
```

Comment: Отлично спасибо.